# How do I read attributes in client end form enum

Tags: java, typescript, rest

I have enum class which is define in server end.

So I need to read Enum value(NO_OF_TYPRES) and description ("Number of tires") in the client end through a rest call.

What get in the client is only the Enum value.

```
public enum SettingType{

    NO_OF_TYPRES("Number of tires"), NO_OF_SEATS("Number of seats");// etc...

    private String description;

    SettingType(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

TypeScript file //client end.

```
export class SettingType{

    public description : string;
    public machineRelated: boolean ;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by defining DTO class in server end with attributes in the enum.

```
public final class SettingTypeDTO{

   private String description;

   public void setDescription(String description){
       this.description = description;
   }

   public String getDescription(){
       return this.description;
   }
}
```